# autocomplete not showing indiviual items

Tags: jquery

I'm following the following [example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for a jQuery autocomplete textbox.

I have a table that I am getting and I make a comma separated string out of.  Which I then assign to the availableTags variable.  When I press a key in the text box I do get a drop down but it is all my values in 1 giant box and I am unable to select just one value.

What is needed to be done for this to behave as I'm expecting?

Here is a [small example](http://jsfiddle.net/8e2pD/2/) that doesn't work at all but on my local machine a variation does.

```
                $(function() {
                    var tags = $('#MainContent_myTable tr .tablecellname').map(function () {
                    return '' $(this).text().trim()+'';
                    }).get().join(',');

                    var availableTags = [tags];

                    $("#tags").autocomplete({
                        source: availableTags
                    });
                    console.log(availableTags);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a string array as stated in the documentation.

In your case change the code like so:

```
$(function () {
     var tags = $('#MainContent_myTable tr .tablecellname').map(function () {
        return '' + $(this).text().trim() + '';
     }).get().join(',');

     var availableTags = tags.split(',');

     $("#tags").autocomplete({
         source: availableTags
     });
     console.log(availableTags);
});
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8e2pD/4/)